# Java Spring Cache-control set max age

Tags: java, spring, caching, cache-control

I'm tryint to set "Cache-control: max-age=60" to don't get data from server more often than 60 seconds. But I really don't know how to do it. I tried something like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/movies")
public List<Movie> getMoviesData() {
    CacheControl.maxAge(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return (List<Movie>) movieRepository.findAll();
}
```

But it doesn't display anything in postman headers. Later I tried this:

In pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1-m02</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is the code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/movies")
public List<Movie> getMoviesData() {
    CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
    cc.setMaxAge(60);
    cc.setPrivate(true);
    return (List<Movie>) movieRepository.findAll();
}
```

But it also display nothing. Now I tried this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/movies")
public List<Movie> getMoviesData(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=60");
    response.addHeader("Last-Modified", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
    return (List<Movie>) movieRepository.findAll();
}
```

And it display `Cache-Control →max-age=60`, but `Last-Modified` refresh everytime when I send get request. So for example I have:

```
Last-Modified →21-01-2017_20:00:41
```

and after few seconds

```
Last-Modified →21-01-2017_20:00:46
```

So the `max-age=60` doesn't work. Somebody have maybe any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to do it correctly?

Comment: Which browser are you testing this with?

Comment: I'm testing it using postman: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop